# WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: team_id, user_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got the following model:

```
class TeamMembership < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :team_id, :user_id
  has_many :users
  belongs_to :team
  belongs_to :user
end
```

When I execute the following:

```
TeamMembership.new(:team_id => 2, :user_id => 3)
```

I get:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: team_id, user_id
 => #<TeamMembership id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, team_id: nil, user_id: nil>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Also, should I be referring to the :team_id column explicitly or should it be :team in the model?

Comment: add owner_id also to attribute accessible , then try

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Thanks, you spotted a mistake in my question; I fixed that but the issue remains!

Comment: how can u have has_many :users and belongs_to :user both, this is not an answer , i just wanna know.

Comment: You're right, that's another error...

Answer (score 2):

Restart your rails console.  It looks like your change hasn't been picked up by the system.